# Logic for padding of an image array

Tags: c, image, padding

Pls. note this isn't any home work question, but work I am doing and where I needed some pointers.

I have a 2D image stored in a 1D array(row major order). I need to pad this image with the replication of the border pixels by 1 row of padding at top, 1 row at bottom, 1 column of padding to right,1 column to left of the image. I am trying to do this in a C code.

e.g. consider the 2D image astored in a 1D array as img[] shown below. Actual image is of size 3x4 (4 rows 3 columns) and after padding by 1 row and 1 column in both directions(up/down/left/right), the final image would be of size 5x6 (6 rows , 5 columns).

```
int img[30] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,7,8,9,0,0,10,11,12,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

In my case, the size of padding is known, just 1 row at top and bottom, 1 column to right and left of the image. So one way i implemented this is by creating a mapping between the indices of the pixels in the given image array to the padded output pixel index. I stored this mapping in a precalculated lookup table and used that table in padding logic.

After padding the output should look like:

```
int img[30] = {1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,9,9,7,7,8,9,9};
```

The lookup table i created was:-

```
int lut[6,6,7,8,8,...];
```

and use this table as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++)
{
img[i] = img[lut[i]]; //something on this lines...
}
```

But I am interested in implementing this image padding logic programatically rathar than using lookup table based method. i.e. I want to calculate the pixel indices in code at run time.
**EDIT** : Also I need to obtain the padded image in place(in same buffer which ofcourse would have provision of storage for the additional padded rows/columns).

Any pointers what would the code look like.

thank you.

-AD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pad_image(int* img, int cols, int rows)
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < cols ; ++i )
    {
        // top and bottom
        img[i]               = img[i+cols];
        img[i+cols*(rows-1)] = img[i+cols*(rows-1)-cols];
    }
    for( int j = 0 ; j < rows ; ++j )
    {
        // left and right
        img[j*cols]        = img[j*cols+1];
        img[j*cols+cols-1] = img[j*cols+cols-2];
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int img[30] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,7,8,9,0,0,10,11,12,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; ++i )
       printf("%d ",img[i]);
    printf("\n");
    pad_image(img,5,6);
    for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; ++i )
       printf("%d ",img[i]);
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your image is already located in the correct position within the destination array, this is reasonably simple - you don't have to move any data around within the array, just copy it.

The following function is called with the padded size (`pad_image(img, 5, 6);` for your example).  It iterates over the filled rows, padding the first and last columns; then duplicates the padded first and last filled rows.

```
#include <string.h>

void pad_image(int img[], int n_cols, int n_rows)
{
    int row;

    if (n_cols < 3 || n_rows < 3)
        return;

    for (row = 1; row < (n_rows - 1); row++)
    {
        /* Duplicate first column in this row */
        img[row * n_cols] = img[row * n_cols + 1];
        /* Duplicate last column in this row */
        img[row * n_cols + n_cols - 1] = img[row * n_cols + n_cols - 2];
    }

    /* Duplicate first row */
    memcpy(&img[0 * n_cols], &img[1 * n_cols], n_cols * sizeof img[0]);
    /* Duplicate last row */
    memcpy(&img[(n_rows - 1) * n_cols], &img[(n_rows - 2) * n_cols], n_cols * sizeof img[0]);
}
```

Comment: This seems slightly more optimal in terms of less number of element copy operations!. Thank you.